# How to implement process of getting updates from a server?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application that will often (for example, once per 5 minutes) ask server for updated version of configuration using HTTP requests.

What is the best way to implement it?

Is [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) suitable for such case? Or may be just a Thread with a loop would be enough?

Comment: Short answer: _Yes_. Use a Service. Slightly broad explanation: Using a Service will ensure that your app will fetch updates in the background. Using a Thread would require your app to running in the foreground. Running a Service in the background is **not** to be confused with running a task using an  `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

[Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) run on UI/Main thread whereas [Intent Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) runs on background thread, it also has another advantage over Service is that Intent Service closes itself after completing its task.

**Service**

> *A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface*

**Intent Service**

> *IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, **and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work***

.

Just create a class which extend [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and `onHandleIntent()` method fetch your Configuration file.

I don't know how are your fetching your Configuration file over HTTP, for the purpose Android provides a framework known as [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html). It provides good HTTP handling over traditional HTTPRequest classes

A simple HTTP request looks like this

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Read More about [fetching data here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).